# Requesting Data not Working in browsers except Chrome, JavaScript and Contentful API

Tags: javascript, syntax, fetch

The requested data works in Chrome but not any other browser that I have. I don't know why. I tried Firefox, Explorer, Edge as well. No response except some ID error in the product cart code.

It works on all browsers if I comment out let cartItem = {           ...Storage.getProduct(id) If not commented out, It causes an error in other browsers SyntaxError: invalid property id. If those lines are commented out the cart has undefined products, so I am working on a solution. Hope I find one.
`

```
 button.addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.target.innerText = "In Cart";
        event.target.disabled = true;
        // get product from products
        let cartItem = {
          ...Storage.getProduct(id),
          amount: 1
        };
```

`
The results are suppose to be what happens in Chrome it outputs the data from the JSON for the products. But all other browsers show no products or data except the above response I have stated above. You can test it in all browsers I have it on Netlify here is the link for further testing: https://comfy1.netlify.com/

Thanks

Comment: are the other browsers updated to versions that support using the rest/spread operator `...`

Comment: Hi I thought it might be something like that. I just updated firefox and it works. I will try that for edge as well. I will have to refactor int o some other syntax for it to be more compatible with older browsers. The versions I have was not that old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I used was incompatible. Does definitely not work with IE. the code snippet below worked with older versions of Firefox and works with EDGE. Works from local JSON and also from an external source API. tested on local machine, cPanel hosting and Netlify.

```
let cartItem = Storage.getProduct(id);
cartItem.amount = 1
```

Thanks everyone who posted feedback on the issue. It pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The rest/spread operator is fully Compatible with:

- Traceur
- Edge 17
- Edge 18
- Edge 19 Preview
- FF 60 ESR
- FF 65
- FF 66
- FF 67 Beta
- FF 68 Nightly
- CH 72, OP 59
- CH 73, OP 60
- CH 74, OP 61
- CH 75, OP 62
- SF 12
- SF 12.1
- SF TP
- WK
- XS6
- Node >= 6.5 < 7
- Node >= 8.10 < 9
- Node >= 10.9 < 11
- Node >= 11
- GraalIVM 1.0
- iOS 12
- iOS 12.2
- Samsung 8.2

There are also some partial compatibilities. When you intend to work with the spread/rest operator, but in general, any ES 6 feature, you will need to ensure that you are testing it in the right version.

Here is the version support table: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

And if you need to support older browsers, you can implement a fallback logic using a transpiler (easier than it sounds). For this purpose BabelJS io is a good option: https://babeljs.io/

You will need to implement fallback logic for older browsers in this case, because your code is not executed properly. If you need us to write a fallback logic for older versions for you, then we will need more information about what Storage.getProduct(id) returns.